# Массовая замена ссылок Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Есть много ссылок на сайте вида

```
<a href="page1/">, 
<a href="category/page1/">
```

Нужно заменить последний слеш на .html, чтобы получилось так

```
<a href="page1.html">, 
<a href="category/page1.html">
```

Есть регуляроне выражение для замены всей ссылки

```
href=.([^'"]*).
```

Подскажите как его переделать, чтобы заменялся только последний слеш в каждой ссылке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(href=['"][^'"]+)/(?=['"])
$1.html
```

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score -2):

```
Ctrl+H
Найти: /"
Заменить на: .html"
```

Comment: Нужно заменить последний, а не все

Comment: Так только последний и заменится. Там же кавычка в конце